# How to allow user to mount Ubuntu partition on Arch Linux without authentication?

Tags: arch-linux, fstab

I have a dual boot system with two partitions for Ubuntu and Arch. In Arch, whenever I need to access the Ubuntu partition, I am asked for the password.

I added a line in fstab as follows:

```
UUID=xxxxxx /run/media/username/Ubuntu ext4 defaults,user,noauto    0   1
```

I do not want to mount it automatically but allow the user to mount it without authentication.

The user is in the users, sys, storage and power groups.

Comment: You should add option `uid=UID` if you wants for one user (UID can be found by `id -u` or add option `gid=GID` for users incorporated into it. (in my system I use **plugdev** : `GID == 46`)

Comment: Can you explain a bit better the plugdev part?

Comment: There is *plugdev* group in my system and my user has incorporated in it. So I use the option `gid=46,users,allow_other,noauto`

Comment: @Costas That would be for a filesystem that doesn't track ownership, such as VFAT. Not for ext4, there's no `uid` or `gid` option because the owner of a file is the owner indicated in the filesystem.

Comment: That's what the `user` option means. What command are you running exactly to do the mounting?

Comment: For the setup youre looking for I wouldnt use fstab at all but udisks.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks

Comment: Simply clicking on the drive in "Files".